# What are the consequences of having a TextToSpeech object in the application class?

Tags: android, android-service, android-context, google-text-to-speech

I currently use text to speech in all of my activities, with a `TextToSpeech` object into each activity (created when the activity is created, shutdown when the activity destroys).

With Google's Speech Synthesis engine, the first loading is very slow (10-15s), but with subsequents activities it's instantaneous, maybe because the TTS engine is already initialized, I don't know. The thing is that when I open an activity and clear the activity stack (with `intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);`), the TTS initialization is slow again (maybe because clearing the stack destroys all TTS objects and release the engine).

So I've come up with the idea of moving the `TextToSpeech` instance in my custom `Application` class, and making it a static "singleton", which will use the context of the first activity to initialize. It will be then shared and used in all of my activities.

I see two problems with that : first, the TTS engine will never be destroyed unless the application process is killed (I guess ?). Second, I've been told to never put a static reference to a `Context`, and I understand why. But for instance the Acapela TTS SDK can only be instantiated once using a context (if you try to create multiple TTS objects in multiple activities, the previous ones will no longer be working), so it must be shared among activites. It may be the same for Android TTS ?

So what should I do ? Is it safe to put a static `TextToSpeech` in my `Application` class ? Or should I go berzerk and create a sticky service with the TTS instance in it ?

Comment: Why not use Fragments, instead of new Activities, if you have to change the screen all the time?

Comment: I don't specify it in my OP but I don't clear the activity stack each time I open a new one, I need to be able to use the back button so fragments are not very appropriate here